# AngularJS : How to make custom Http service more robust for error handling?

Tags: angularjs

Hello i have this simple custom AngularJS service for HTTP requests:

```
angular.module('MaxRelax')
    .factory('httpSrv', function httpSrv($http, $q) {

        return {
            getData: getData
        };

        function getData(method, url) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            $http({method:method, url:url})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Success");
                    console.log(status);
                    def.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    getErrorMessage(status);
                    def.reject("Failed to get");

                });

            return def.promise;
        }

        // I WANT HANDLE ERROR STATES HERE AND RETURN FOMRATTED MESSAGE WITH ERROR 
        // DESCRIPTION IN CASE OF THE ERROR STATE (service unavailable, 404, etc..)
        function getErrorMessage(status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
```

Which is called from the controllers by this way:

```
httpSrv.getData("GET",APP_CONST.MP3_ACTUAL_VERSION_URL).then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

I would like to make this service more robust in the way of the error handling. For example:

```
httpSrv.getData("GET",APP_CONST.MP3_ACTUAL_VERSION_URL).
.success(function(data) {
            // EVERYTHING IS OK
        });
.error(function(data) {
            // CALL  METHOD getErrorMessage OF THE httpSrv SERVICE to get formatted error message
        });
```

How i should to update my service to do it in the right way please?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Nobody knows how to improve this service?

Comment: The term "more robust" is very vague - I'm not sure what you mean and where you have a problem in your current code.